# Module for image upload and resize

Tags: node.js, module

Is there a module for Node.JS that handles uploads and then automatic modifications of the newly-uploaded file?

I am coming from a PHP background and I used to use the following class, which has always been of great use for said purpose: http://www.verot.net/php_class_upload_samples.htm

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I suppose there's none? oh well...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is one module that does all of it but I use [formidable](https://github.com/felixge/node-formidable) and [GraphicsMagick](http://aheckmann.github.com/gm/) and they work pretty nicely. If you're using Express you can just use the bodyParser and gm.

For the front end, [jQuery File Upload](http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/) is a good drag and drop uploader using query.

Comment: I'm just like... meh. Node.js seemed really interesting at first, and it still really is for some things, but it really cannot be compared to other, more mature, languages. I mean, having to rely on a thirdy part software is just out of the question.

Comment: Like having to use a third-party server? Kidding. That's sort of the idea though - having a core with most of the functionality but is still lean and then you can choose which modules to add for your particular case. There are quite a few really solid, well-maintained modules that I stick with.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an exact match to what you are looking for, but if you can have ImageMagick installed on your server this looks like a good tool to do the resize job: https://github.com/rsms/node-imagemagick